# Cant set HISTSIZE lower than 1

Tags: bash, zsh

For some reason, I cant set HISTSIZE smaller than 1

```
$ export HISTSIZE="2"; echo $HISTSIZE
2
$ export HISTSIZE="1"; echo $HISTSIZE
1
$ export HISTSIZE="0"; echo $HISTSIZE 
1
$ export HISTSIZE="-1"; echo $HISTSIZE 
1
```

Interestingly, setting this to a non-numeric value also results in 1:

```
$ export HISTSIZE="test"; echo $HISTSIZE
1
```

It seems some kind of validation is being performed silently. Any idea where I should be looking?

I want to set `HISTSIZE` to -1 so that I can get infinite history.

I am currently using zsh 5.1.1 with oh-my-zsh

Worth pointing out that `HISTFILESIZE` does not have this issue:

```
$ export HISTFILESIZE="-1"; echo $HISTFILESIZE
-1
```

Comment: `HISTFILESIZE` isn't a `zsh` parameter (see `man zshparams`)...

Comment: If you want to have virtually unlimited history in zsh, just set `HISTSIZE` to a very large number.  For example `HISTSIZE= 2147483647` (2^31-1), which is sufficiently large to add one command every second for the next 68 years. The maximum may depend on the hardware, on my machine it is `HISTSIZE=9223372036854775807` (2^63-1), which is sufficient for 292 billion years at the same rate. Note, that you also need to set `SAVEHIST` in order to actually have the history written to the history file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by `histsizesetfn()` in `zsh`'s [`Src/params.c`](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/params.c#l4193):

```
void
histsizesetfn(UNUSED(Param pm), zlong v)
{
    if ((histsiz = v) < 1)
        histsiz = 1;
    resizehistents();
}
```

so the value of `HISTSIZE` can never been set to a value less than 1.

Comment: Well this seems silly. Why would they limit this if negative values are allowed?

Comment: What makes you think negative values are allowed?

Comment: from `man bash` - "HISTSIZE: The number of commands to remember in the command history (see HISTORY below).  If the value is 0, commands are  not  saved  in  the  history  list.  Numeric values less than zero result in every command being saved on the history list (there is no limit).  The shell sets the default  value to 500 after reading any startup files."

Comment: You're running Zsh though, so `bash`'s documentation doesn't apply... See `man zshparam` for Zsh.

Comment: you're right. I wrongly assumed that HISTSIZE would be the same for zsh and bash because of their similarities :/